# How to get object from file that imported another file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import

Say I have a python file called `fileOne.py` that imports `fileTwo.py`. Is there a way for `fileTwo.py` to access the objects from `fileOne.py` dynamically? So `fileTwo.py` doesn't need to know the name of the file that will import it, and instead can do something like this: `FILE_THAT_IMPORTED_ME.myFunction()`.

Basically I want to know if there is a way to access objects from the 'parent' file that is importing a script, from said script.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the file which imported you by doing `import __main__` and `__main__` will contain the parent module.

`a.py#`

```
import b
print(b)
```

`b.py#`

```
import __main__
print(__main__)
```

Executing `a.py` will result in

```
<module '__main__' from '/home/jonatan/PycharmProjects/tests/test/a.py'>
<module 'b' from '/home/jonatan/PycharmProjects/tests/test/b.py'>
```

**Note** that `__main__` is being printed before `b` since the module b has to complete its loading before continue the file `a`.